# Trying to get IPs from file and use it as Inventory in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I get list of IP address in test.text file from which I am trying to get the IP in loop
and then try to get in group or variable and use it as hosts (dynamic_groups)

Below is my playlist

```
---
- name: provision stack
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - name: Get Instance IP Addresses From File
      shell: cat /home/user/test.text
      register: serverlist
    - debug: msg={{ serverlist.stdout_lines }}
    - name: Add Instance IP Addresses to temporary inventory groups
      add_host:
        groups: dynamic_groups
        hostname: "{{item}}"
      with_items: serverlist.stdout_lines

- hosts: dynamic_groups
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: True
  serial: 1
  vars:
    ansible_connection: "{{ connection_type }}"
    ansible_ssh_user: "{{ ssh_user_name }}"
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ ssh_private_key_file }}"

  tasks:
     .....
     .....
```

After running above playbbok I am getting below error

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "192.168.1.10",
        "192.168.1.11",
        "192.168.1.50"
    ]
}

TASK [Add Instance IP Addresses to temporary inventory groups] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=serverlist.stdout_lines)

PLAY [dynamic_groups] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Some Command] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [serverlist.stdout_lines]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname serverlist.stdout_lines: Name or service not known", "unreachable": true}
```

What Am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you have each number in different line?>

Comment: What is this "Some Command" Task ? because that's your error where it tries to do ssh , you might not be reading right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is correct way to use variable

```
    - name: Add Instance IP Addresses to temporary inventory groups
      add_host:
        groups: working_hosts
        hostname: "{{item}}"
      with_items: "{{ serverlist.stdout_lines }}"
```

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As reported in fatal error message *"Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname serverlist.stdout_lines"*, it is trying to connect to "serverlist.stdout_lines", not to a valid IP.

This is caused by an error when passing variable to *with_items*. In your task:

```
with_items: serverlist.stdout_lines
```

it is passing serverlist.stdout_lines string and not its value.

*With_items* requires variable definition using "{{ ... }}" (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items).

This is the correct way for your task:

```
- name: Add Instance IP Addresses to temporary inventory groups
  add_host:
    groups: dynamic_groups
    hostname: "{{item}}"
  with_items: "{{ serverlist.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: Yes, This works As @Jaydeep suggested earlier. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ansible-playbook -i inventory_file_name playbook.yaml for this. inventory_file is the file containing your groups and ips.